# Raw SQL query in Entity Framework Core does not work properly when using string.Format

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, string.format

This query works properly:

```
var results = _mp4Db.Videos.FromSql(
            "Select * 
             from Video 
             where isValid = 1 
               and (contains(Subject,'\"" + text + "" + '*' + "\"') 
                    or contains(Description,'\"" + text + "" + '*' + "\"')) 
             order by 
                 case 
                    when contains(Subject,'\"" + text + "" + '*' + "\"') 
                       then 1 
                       else 2 
                 end, 
                 len(Subject) 
             offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only ");
```

But if I use `string.Format` for a clearer code, it does not return the result it should:

```
 var results = _mp4Db.Videos.FromSql(
            "Select * 
             from Video 
             where isValid=1 
                 and (contains(Subject,'\"{0}{1}\"') 
                 or contains(Description,'\"{0}{1}\"')) 
             order by case 
                 when contains(Subject,'\"{0}{1}\"') 
                     then 1 
                     else 2 End , 
                 LEN(Subject) 
             Offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only ", text, '*');
```

Any idea what's missing here?

Comment: I **don't see** any `string.Format` in your second example - just adding the placeholders like `{0}` isn't enough - you **must use** `string.Format()` explicitly

Comment: Yes,Haven't noticed that one as it was converted by Resharper auto-correct ,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `$` operator and execute your query by calling `.ToList()` method:

```
var results = _mp4Db.Videos.FromSql(
    $"Select * from Video where isValid=1 and (contains(Subject,'\"{text}{'*'}\"') " +
        $"or contains(Description,'\"{text}{'*'}\"')) " +
        $"order by case when contains(Subject,'\"{text}{'*'}\"') then 1 " +
        $"else 2 End , LEN(Subject) Offset 20 rows fetch next 20 rows only "
).ToList();
```